# Cannot retrieve active members only

Tags: conditional-tags, users

Below is a page template where I'm trying to retrieve active members metadata (of Restrict Content Pro). Displaying users' meta is working just fine; but I can't get ONLY active members to display, rather than everyone. I wondered if perhaps there a simple error in the syntax below that might correct this.

I need to check if a member is active [that's using `if( rcp_is_active() )]`, where all members are also subscribers on the site `[ $members = get_users( $args ); foreach ($members as $member)]` .

```
<?php
/**
 * This file adds the User Directory template to the Parallax Pro Theme.
 *
 * @author StudioPress
 * @package Parallax
 * @subpackage Customizations
 */

/*
Template Name: Directory
*/

add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'ogs_directory', 5 );
function ogs_directory() {
        $args = array(
            'blog_id'      => 1, // unless yours is a multisite install, you shouldn't need to change this
            'exclude'      => array(), // IDs of users that need to be excluded
            'orderby'      => 'display_name' // Sort by 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'; defaults to 'login'
         );
         $members = get_users( $args );
         if( rcp_is_active() ) {
        foreach ($members as $member)       

            echo '<p>';
            echo '<strong>Name: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->first_name ).  '' ;
            echo '<strong> </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->last_name ).  '<br/> ' ;
            if ( $member->rcp_address ) {
            echo '<strong>Address: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->rcp_address ).  '<br/> ' ;
            }
            if ( $member->rcp_univ_1 ) {
            echo '<strong>University: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->rcp_univ_1 ).  '<br/> ' ;
            }
        echo '</p>';

         }   }

//* Run the Genesis loop
genesis();
```

Comment: Does `rcp_is_active()` check to see if an individual member is active? If so, I suspect it belongs inside your `foreach()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces for `foreach` is missing. Try this:

```
/*
Template Name: Directory
*/

add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'ogs_directory', 5 );

function ogs_directory() {
        $args = array(
            'blog_id'      => 1, // unless yours is a multisite install, you shouldn't need to change this
            'exclude'      => array(), // IDs of users that need to be excluded
            'orderby'      => 'display_name' // Sort by 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'; defaults to 'login'
         );
         $members = get_users( $args );
         if( rcp_is_active() ) {
        foreach ($members as $member)   {


              echo '<p>';
              echo '<strong>Name: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->first_name ).  '' ;
              echo '<strong> </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->last_name ).  '<br/> ' ;
              if ( $member->rcp_address ) {
              echo '<strong>Address: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->rcp_address ).  '<br/> ' ;
              }
              if ( $member->rcp_univ_1 ) {
              echo '<strong>University: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->rcp_univ_1 ).  '<br/> ' ;
              }
              echo '</p>';
          }  // end foreach  

         } // end if   

       } // end function

//* Run the Genesis loop
genesis();
```

Comment: I did have curly braces for each missing, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

`if( rcp_is_active()` wasn't right for what I wanted to do. I needed `rcp_get_members()`. Changing that, and adding in the missing brackets from above allowed me to produce the result I wanted. Thank you.

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'ogs_directory', 5 );
function ogs_directory() {
        $args = array(
            'blog_id'      => 1, // unless yours is a multisite install, you shouldn't need to change this
            'exclude'      => array(), // IDs of users that need to be excluded
            'orderby'      => 'display_name' // Sort by 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'; defaults to 'login'
         );
         $members = rcp_get_members();
        foreach ($members as $member) {     

            echo '<p>';
            echo '<strong>Name: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->first_name ).  '' ;
            echo '<strong> </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->last_name ).  '<br/> ' ;
            if ( $member->rcp_address ) {
            echo '<strong>Address: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->rcp_address ).  '<br/> ' ;
            }
            if ( $member->rcp_univ_1 ) {
            echo '<strong>University: </strong>' .esc_attr( $member->rcp_univ_1 ).  '<br/> ' ;
            }
        echo '</p>';

         }   }

//* Run the Genesis loop
genesis();
```